# Normalizing State with React useState?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, normalization, use-state, normalizr

Is this a common practice and generally recommended, also for `useState`?

Would it generally be advisable to turn this...

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "author": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Paul"
  },
  "title": "My awesome blog post",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "324",
      "commenter": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nicole"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

...into something like this:

```
{
  result: "123",
  entities: {
    "articles": {
      "123": {
        id: "123",
        author: "1",
        title: "My awesome blog post",
        comments: [ "324" ]
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "1": { "id": "1", "name": "Paul" },
      "2": { "id": "2", "name": "Nicole" }
    },
    "comments": {
      "324": { id: "324", "commenter": "2" }
    }
  }
}
```

(example taken from [here](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr))

I know this was a thing with redux, but I'm struggling to decide whether it makes sense with newer things like `useState`, `useReducer` or just Reacts context api etc.

In my use case, it seems like I could benefit from doing it this way, but not by so much, since the way I want to show the data sort of concurs with the way it comes back from the backend.

Comment: I'd say it makes sense to normalise the state this way, if you additionally create separate states for articles, users and comments. This way, adding a new comment to an article, you prevent the re-rendering of the whole page.